# Cannot use column of outside reference in my inside query

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am using SQL query like below:

```
SELECT distinct uf.SystemName as System ,uf.SystemId,
            (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c.SystemId = uf.SystemTypeId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            FROM OPENJSON((SELECT TOP 1 CAST(JsonStringColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM RefTable where TagId = (Select top 1 TagId from CSSTAGS where projectid='9abbeecf-15a4-412f-ba0c-358b8f09ac9e')))
            WITH (Data NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) a
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.Data)
            WITH (System NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) b
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.System) 
            WITH (SystemId NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.SystemId') c
            ) As SystemIdExists
FROM Table1 uf
```

I am not able to use uf.SystemId inside my second select query which throwing below error: Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: that's some horrible SQL

Comment: It also contains syntax errors.

Comment: Note, as well, that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: I have updated the query, Could you please help me now

Comment: You can't `SUM` on a column from an outer scope, @Avinash . Without sample data, and expected results, we can't help you. Though it seems you shuold just move `c.SystemId = uf.SystemTypeId` to the `WHERE`, and then you can just do a `COUNT`.

Answer (score -1):

Adding Where condition to second select query resolved my issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).